# BroadcastReceiver - onReceive Not Being Called

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I send a Broadcast by doing:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.usmaan.myApp.DATA_RECEIVED");
intent.putExtra("matchId", newRowId);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This is the Service that wraps up the `AsyncTask` which runs Broadcasts the above:

```
<service
   android:name=".services.DataService"
   android:exported="false" />
```

In my Activity, I register a `Receiver` in `onResume`:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.usmaan.myApp.DATA_RECEIVED");
registerReceiver(mDataReceiver, intentFilter);
```

The `BroadReceiver looks like this:

```
private class DataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final long matchId = intent.getLongExtra("matchId", 0);
        Toast.makeText(LaunchActivity.this, "" + matchId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

The `onReceive` is never fired. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either use `LocalBroadcastManager` in both places (`sendBroadcast()` and `registerReceiver()`), or do not use `LocalBroadcastManager` at all. Right now, you have a mismatched pair.

Comment: The onReceive is now being fired but it's not showing the Toast on screen....How come?

Comment: Still not working. It's hitting onReceive and running the Toast code but I don't see a Toast.

Comment: You missed show() to chain. Try this:  Toast.makeText(context, "" + matchId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();